# Running a program programmatically through command line

Tags: c++, windows, macos, command-line

How can I run a program programmaticaly through command line and get its return value? I would like to have a way that works on both Windows 7 and MacOS X, but if I need to program it differently per OS I would do that too

Comment: most platforms have `system()` for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [system](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/system/) to call a program and retrieve its return value.

An example would be

```
int returnValue = system("C:\\SomeProgram.exe");
```